# python adding spaces in email body between lists of lists

Tags: python, list, email

Assuming I have the following list:

```
ListofLists = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

I want to add the list of lists to the body of a email, something like that:

```
body = "Here are the informations" + ListofLists
```

I would like to seperate the two lists and print the lists each in a seperate line, so it looks like a table, how could I do that?

What I want as an Output is the following:

```
Number 1  Number 2  Number 3  Number 4  Number 5  
   2         3         4         5         6
   8         9        10        11        11
```

Comment: Show your effort please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: Oh well, I didnt see that tho, that helps a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
listOfLists = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
for i in range(len(listOfLists[0])):
    print('Number',(i+1), end = "  ")
for i in range(len(listOfLists)):
    print()
    for j in listOfLists[i]:
        print('  ',j, end = (7-len(str(j+1)))*' ')
```

makes output like this:

```
Number 1  Number 2  Number 3  Number 4  Number 5  Number 6  
   2         3         4         5         6         7      
   8         9        10        11        12        13
```

Comment: Thank you! that helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean:

```
listOfLists = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

body = ("here are the informations")

for a in listOfLists:
    print(body + str(a))
```

output looks like:

```
here are the informations[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
here are the informations[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: No, I would like something like a "Number1" and below that the first numbers of each list and so on.